# Filter wont work if I press backspace in react app

Tags: reactjs, filter

I am pretty new to react and trying to learn stuff. I wanted to filter the list based on input and it works but if I misspell a name and then press backspace and then type the correct name, the list wont show up.

Here is the filter part

```
  const handleFilterChange=(event)=>{
    setFilter(event.target.value)
    setPersons(persons.filter((person) => (person.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))));

  }
```

Here is the entire code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
const Name =({name, phone})=>{
  return(
    <li>{name}: {phone}</li>
  )
}
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345', id: 3 },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122', id: 4 }
  ]) 
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone]= useState('')
  const [filt,setFilter]=useState('')

  const addName=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("newName ",newName)
    console.log("phone ",phone)
    console.log('clicked', event.target);
    const found = persons.find(person=> person.name === newName);
    console.log("found ",found)
    if(found){
      window.alert(`${newName} is already added to phonebook`);
    }
    else{
      const addNewName={
        name: newName,
        number: phone
      }
      setPersons(persons.concat(addNewName))
      setNewName("")
      setPhone("")
    }
    
    
  }
  const handleNameChange=(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewName(event.target.value)  
    
  }
 
  const handleFilterChange=(event)=>{
    setFilter(event.target.value)
    setPersons(persons.filter((person) => (person.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))));

  }
  const handlePhoneChange=(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setPhone(event.target.value)
  }
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName}>
        <div>
          filter shown with: <input value={filt} onChange={handleFilterChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange}/>
          <br></br>
          phone: <input value={phone} onChange={handlePhoneChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      {persons.map(person=> <Name key={person.id} name={person.name} phone={person.number}/>)}     
    </div>
    
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: The problem is that once you've filtered the list, the whole data is just this filtered list. So if your filter is 'Ad', it will show 'Ada Lovelace', and your list of persons is just this one entry, so you can't filter by say 'Ar' to get 'Arto Hellas' -- that entry is simply not there anymore.

Comment: On top of what @tromygy has mentioned, the list of filtered persons should probably be a `useMemo()` thing, that returns a filtered persons list based on on filter criteria, without needing to mutate the original data at all.

Comment: Ah now I understand. Thanks a lot for the explanation tromgy. Thank you for the suggestion @Terry! I looked up and implemented useMemo() and now it works as I want it to.